# Installing alongside Win7; entire disk shows as unallocated

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I am trying to install 10.10 along with a Win7 installation, but I can't. When I run the installer it says that the entire disk is free (unallocated). If I try to run the "Try Ubuntu" thing instead, it *can* access the other partition(s), but when I run GParted it will say the disk is free.

I've read somewhere this is due to buggy GPT support; but does anyone know who to fix this?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots from Disk utility so that we 'see' how are your drives & partitions set up?

Comment: Can we get the output of `sudo fdisk -l` from the Live-System?

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Have you partitioned the drive from within win7? you should.

Answer (score 2):

Parted, which is used by Ubuntu's installer, generally complains when you try to list partitons on a drive whose partition table is in some way invalid. Unfortunately the error from libparted isn't displayed by either Ubuntu's installer or GParted. Instead, because of the error, they get no information about the existing partitions and these front ends act as if the drive is not partitioned at all. You'll need to determine what is wrong with your partition table and fix it before attempting to install Ubuntu. That is why I asked you to post the output of `sudo parted -l`, as parted *will* tell you what problem it has detected and from that we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when I had primary partitions intertwined with logical partitions.(e.g.: primary partition, logical, primary).

I solved it by moving the logical partition at the end of the partition table.You can do that with a Windows utility such as Acronis Disk Director or Partition Magic